# How to save powershell script results to a file

Tags: file, powershell, count, directory

I am using the script below to display all the subfolders' names and the count of files in those folders. I cannot figure out how to save the results to a file. I have tried everything I could and searched online for hours.

```
dir -recurse |  ?{ $_.PSIsContainer } | %{ Write-Host $_.FullName (dir $_.FullName | Measure-Object).Count }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `Write-Host`. That cmdlet writes to the console only (i.e., you cannot redirect it to a file).

Use something like this instead:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | ForEach-Object {
  $_.FullName
}
```

Comment: I am sorry I am new to PS and can see that you didnt put the whole script because it doesnt have the part to count and when I run it it just gives me the list of the folders, not the count of files in each folder. Could you put the whole script I need to run to get the count? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found another way of doing it that lets me save to a file:

```
ls -rec | ? {$_.mode -match 'd'} | select FullName,  @{N='Count';E={(ls $_.FullName | measure).Count}} | Out-File C:\results.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I took your code and I upgraded it. try this:

```
$OUserOut = @()
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | ForEach-Object {
  $ObjProperties = New-Object PSObject
  Add-Member -InputObject $ObjProperties -MemberType NoteProperty -Name FullName -Value $_.FullName
  Add-Member -InputObject $ObjProperties -MemberType NoteProperty -Name InternalObj -Value (dir $_.FullName | Measure-Object).Count
  $OUserOut += $ObjProperties
}
$OUserOut | Out-GridView -Title "Objects"
$OUserOut |  Export-Csv $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Out.csv
```

The two last lines have the information for the output file. The "Out-GridView" it's a table for show you the information, and the other line it's for export the result to a csv file.